# Create unique index oracle with where clause

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I m trying to create a unique index with where clause like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX cmt_unique_sid_yid_ct
          ON COMMENTARY (source_id, year_id)
       WHERE comment_type_id = (
         select comment_type_name 
         from comment_type 
         where comment_type_name = 'Final'
       );
```

Getting this error :

```
02158. 00000 -  "invalid CREATE INDEX option"
*Cause:    An option other than COMPRESS, NOCOMPRESS, PCTFREE, INITRANS,
           MAXTRANS, STORAGE, TABLESPACE, PARALLEL, NOPARALLEL, RECOVERABLE,
           UNRECOVERABLE, LOGGING, NOLOGGING, LOCAL, or GLOBAL was specified.
*Action:   Choose one of the valid CREATE INDEX options.
```

I m basically trying restrict comments with type `Final` from comment_type table, to only one row per source/year. So scope to :

```
comment_type_name | source_id | year_id
```

How can I do this with SQL, specifically oracle?

Comment: This may be the model you want https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4092298900346548432.  However, you may consider doing this with a view to do the logic as well.

Comment: Lookup function based index, that is what you want.

Comment: @Raj can you point me to the example, I found this https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/function-based-indexes doesn't seem related, maybe I m not understanding this correctly

Answer (score 1):

No such thing in Oracle, just some workaround with function based indexes:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX cmt_unique_sid_yid_ct
ON COMMENTARY (
  case when comment_type_name = 'Final' then source_id end,
  case when comment_type_name = 'Final' then year_id end
);
```

Sample query that can use this index:

```
select * from commentary
where 
case when comment_type_name = 'Final' then source_id end = :B1
and case when comment_type_name = 'Final' then year_id end = :B2
;
```